# Convert a method to an object to send via HTTP

Tags: java

Are their any good tutorials out there that show how to convert a method, to an object then send it via HTTP and reverse the process on the other end. I did it once long ago on an RMI server and I can't find any good tutorials online that show the full process.

Comment: Personally, I think your best bet is to simply design objects that happen to send and/or receive messages.  But if you *must* have some kind of object mapping framework, then 1) RMI (using the RMIC tool) is a good choice, 2) Web services (using the JAX-WS and JAXB tools) are also a good choice, 3) You could look at higher-level frameworks like [Spring](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html).  IMHO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since serializing a method directly is not possible you have to be creative in how you serialize the method information. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769842/serialization-of-method-object-in-java-is-possible) is a link to a similar question about serializing methods.

In reference to sending something over HTTP [here](http://javatidbits.blogspot.com/2004/12/sending-and-receiving-objects-over.html) is a tutorial that talks about serializing an object and sending it over a URL connection.

If you combine the information from both sources you should be able to solve your problem. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using RMI you should use RESTful web service in JAVA which converts the object into JSON object on one side and converts back to object on other side..Read out following links for Restful service tutorial

http://avilyne.com/?p=105

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-tomcat/

http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html